# Telnet server within C++ app

Tags: c++, linux, posix, telnet

I am writing an application to run on a robot. Currently, it is headless, but I want to be able to telnet directly to the application with no authentication and access a shell that I will write.

Is this possible? Would it be practical or are there much easier solutions?

Comment: Telnet uses TCP protocol using socket communication, and you just need a socket library (e.g. boost::asio or you can even build your own)

Comment: You could consider using an HTTP server library in your robot application (e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely possible.

However, if you are using Linux, you may just as well just let your application do it's I/O to the terminal, and use telnet to log in. If you set up a user to use your application as the "login-shell", it will allow direct access to that user called "robot" (for example) (and you can set it to have no password too) - then just do `telnet -l robot machine port`.

This would save you the effort of writing your own telnet client, and give you almost identical functionality.

Comment: But note that telnet is *very* insecure. If you can get away with it, use ssh.

Comment: Yes, `ssh` would be a much better solution - in fact, you could use a generated key to avoid passwords, but still have a reasonably secure system. This obviously only matter if you are doing something beyond building a robot for your own purposes in your bedroom.

Comment: It will be on a very secure and isolated network. I choose telnet because it has no encryption and seems much easier to implement. However, I think this answerr might solve the issue!

Comment: If you are indeed using a telnet/ssh daemon that simply runs the application as a shell, then you have "no difficulty" with the protocol/encryption, because that is handled by the daemon, which is a separate process. So it'll "Just work".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom shell, why would you need telnet? Your shell can have a daemon component to listen on given port and then hand over the interaction to whatever REPL your shell would implement.

Comment: No. i am creating an application that I want to access from elsewhere.  There will be a minimal command system that will allow application debugging and application output